# echo $PATH shows a Python.Framework directory. Changes are reversed after restarting terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, path, zsh, iterm2

So I ran `brew doctor` and this is what came out:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
```

Then when I type `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` and echo $PATH, it gives me `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` BUT, when I restart the terminal (iTerm2 zsh), it goes back to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

This $PATH doesn't look right. I don't know much about $PATH, but is there a way to fix it to how it should be? I also tried editing the `.bash_profile` and put `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` path instead of the python one - still no luck when I echo $PATH it's still the one with python. Please help me this is frustrating.

Comment: Check you `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to see where it's setting `PATH`.

Comment: @Later_72 : It is not clear to me, whether you are refering to _bash_ or to _zsh_.  The PATH can be set in any of the dot-files which are run on startup of a shell.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm referring specifically to bash. However, I've tried changing both (in the dot files) and it still reverts back to the python path.

Comment: @If you set your specific PATH somewhere in the dot files, and after starting a terminal, the PATH is not set, it means that either your dot files are not sourced, or something is changing the PATH again after you have set it. I would first put a `set -x` at the start of each of the involved dot files, and a `echo $PATH` at the end, and then starting a new terminal. This should get you an idea of where the problem is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `PATH` into `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`.

Because `~/.bash_profile` effects only when bash is invoked as a login shell, which means you should re-login or run bash with the `--login` option.

`~/.bashrc`, instead, will be read and executed when an interactive shell is started. This works when you restart your terminal.

---

Edit: Sorry, I find out that your shell is zsh. The answer above is for bash.

For zsh, put `PATH` into `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`.

> Commands are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`. If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from `/etc/zsh/zprofile` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`.
>
> Then,  if  the  shell is interactive,  commands  are  read  from `/etc/zsh/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`.
>
> Finally, if the shell is a login shell, `/etc/zsh/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.

If you don't set the `ZDOTDIR` variable, then these files are located at your home directory.

Comment: I do not have $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc in my system. Do I need to create it?

Comment: @Later_72 I guess you don't set the $ZDOTDIR variable, so just create ~/.zshrc file (the tilde here means your home directory) ,  and put $PATH into in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of various question around Bash/Zsh & co, and corresponding `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` and so; if you have enough access, you may consider defining the PATH variable in a dedicated file under `/etc/profile.d` directory.

For instance:

```
sudo cat > /etc/profile.d/variousEnvironmentUpdates.sh <<EOF
PATH=<what you want first>:$PATH
EOF
```

Comment: Does it answer your question?